# What became available_attrs on Django 3?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0, django-3.1

First of all, I'm new to Django, so please be nice with me :D

I'm currently adapting .py files for Django 3 because the files I have are compatible for Django 2. So, some changes have been made for the new version and in a file, it's written :

```
@wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
```

With the import :

```
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs
```

I searched for an adaptation of available_attrs, and I quickly found that it has been removed for the new version.

And when I launch the code, I have this :

```
ImportError : cannot import name 'available_attrs' from 'django.utils.decorators'
```

So I was wondering what should I write instead of available_attrs to make it work ?

PS : Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`available_attrs()` only ever existed to help bridge between Python 2 and Python 3. This is documented in the [Django 3.0 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#removed-private-python-2-compatibility-apis):

> ### Removed private Python 2 compatibility APIs
>
> While Python 2 support was removed in Django 2.0, some private APIs weren’t removed from Django so that third party apps could continue using them until the Python 2 end-of-life.
>
> Since we expect apps to drop Python 2 compatibility when adding support for Django 3.0, we’re removing these APIs at this time.
>
> - *[...]*
> - `django.utils.decorators.available_attrs()` - This function returns `functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS`

If the `@wraps()` in your sample line is the standard [`functools.wraps()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), then you can just *entirely* remove `assigned=available_attrs(...)`, because `functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS` is the default value for `assigned`:

```
@wraps(view_func)
```

otherwise, just use `functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS` directly.

Comment: @MaximeTeillaud: as for the permission errors, see the [documentation on default permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) and on [creating permissions programmatically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions). There is a clash between those two, where you defined view permissions that are also created automatically. Just remove the custom view permissions. The JSONField warnings should be self-evident, you can change where the field is imported from.